# And/Or combination in VBA

Tags: vba, or-operator, and-operator

I am confused on how 'and' 'or' statements work together.
I am trying to make a (something Or something) statement work as part of an 'and' statement but cannot figure out the logic
The problem is illustrated by the following two code blocks.
The first one works fine..the second fails with Run time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method". The error refers to the "If j.Enabled..." line.
In my opinion both should run..can anyone elaborate on why this isn't so?

Code block 1 (runs)

```
Private Sub Fini_cbn_Click()
Dim j As Control
For Each j In Controls
    If j.Enabled = True And j.Tag = "4" Then
        If j.Value = "<NA>" Or j.Value = "" Then
            j.BackColor = &HFFFF&
            Else
            j.BackColor = &H80000005
        End If
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Code block 2 (fails)

```
Private Sub Fini_cbn_Click()
Dim j As Control
For Each j In Controls
    If j.Enabled = True And j.Tag = "4" And (j.Value = "<NA>" Or j.Value = "") Then
        j.BackColor = &HFFFF&
        Else
        j.BackColor = &H80000005
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: What application is this for?  Access?

Comment: My first guess is that every control doesn't have a "value" property and so one of controls you are looping through is missing it.  Try to msgbox j.value and see if it errors out then and what control it is erroring out on.

Comment: To add to @OpiesDad: In your second example, `j.Value` is invariably evaluated and will error if `.Value` is not available when, for example, `j.Enabled = False`. In your first example, this problem is circumvented — and thus this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA doesn't [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that the entire expression gets evaluated *everytime*.

So here

> ```
> If j.Enabled = True And j.Tag = "4" Then
>     If j.Value = "<NA>" Or j.Value = "" Then
> ```

`j.Value` only gets evaluated ***IF*** `j.Enabled And j.Tag = "4"` and everything is fine.

But here

> ```
> If j.Enabled = True And j.Tag = "4" And (j.Value = "<NA>" Or j.Value = "") Then
> ```

The entire statement gets evaluated "at once". So, there must be a control in your collection that does not have a `Value` property. Since the property doesn't exist, it can't evaluate the statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, the full if statement is being executed for each control.  So, if there are any controls that do not have a value property, then the "j.value" part of the if statement is evaluated, but the control doesn't have the property.

In the first version, I'm guessing that you have only set the tag and enabled controals that have the "value" property.  So the "j.value" property is never attempted to be found.